# Coppying Listbox numbers to Array c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am trying to copy items from listbox to an array. 
But I missing something here. I get error Method name expected.

I have three errors:

Error   CS1955  Non-invocable member 'ListBox.Items' cannot be used like a method.

Error   CS0201  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Error   CS0149  Method name expected    WindowsFormsApp6

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    int i;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Random rand = new Random();
        for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(rand.Next(0, 10));
        }


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        for (i = 0; i <= listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            string[] strArray = new string[11];

            strArray(i) == listBox1.Items(i);

            label1.Text = "Coppied items"; 


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use square brackets `[ ]` instead of parenthesis `( )` to reference indexes of an array

Comment: Arrays are accessed with [], not with (). This is not VB.Net

Comment: You should also declare `i` locally, in your `for` conditions: `for (int i = 0; ...`

Comment: You also should declare and instantiate your `strArray` outside the `for` loop. Currently you're setting it to a new array on each iteration

Comment: And `==` is a comparison, not an assignment. `strArray[i] == listBox1.Items[i];` is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
strArray(i) == listBox1.Items(i);
```

there are two issues.

1. You use [] to access arrays, not parenthesis.
2. You meant to use the = operator to assign the value, not ==. '==' is for checking a condition.

Result:

```
strArray[i] = listBox1.Items[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with the code. The main answer to your question is that you reference array items using square brackets, not parenthesis.

But you also do not need to declare your `i` variable at the class level. It should be declared at the lowest required scope, which is in the `for` loop.

You also should declare your `strArray` outside the loop, otherwise it is getting recreated every time. It's not clear to me if you should declare it in the method or in the class level, since you don't show any code that actually uses it, however.

Also, you are using the comparison operator (`==`) instead of the assignment operator (`=`) when adding items to your array.

Here's how you can fix these issues:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(rand.Next(0, 10));
    }
}

private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] strArray = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        strArray[i] = listBox1.Items[i];
    }

    label1.Text = "Coppied items"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have now. The code compiles but the messages does not show on the label.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] strArray = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            strArray[i] = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
        }

        label1.Text = "Coppied items";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ListItemCollection.CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx) method to do this without a loop.

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] strArray = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
    listBox1.Items.CopyTo(strArray, strArray.GetLowerBound(0));
    label1.Text = "Copied items";
}
```

Comment: Looking at you answer I suspect you mean the message isn't showing on label1. There is not much to much that can go wrong with that statement. The code is running and you are looking at a label control named label1, correct?